# RASBMC Bluetooth Playback over Sound Bar

Tags: raspbmc, wireless, audio, kodi, bluetooth

I have a LG Sound Bar that allows audio playback using Bluetooth.

I'd like to play audio from XBMC on raspbmc over the Sound Bar.

At the same time, Id still like the audio from HDMI to still playback normally over the TV.
The goal being that the same audio source would play in two different rooms wireless.

Could this be done?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Welcome to SE, please see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/180072   I think you can route audio to two places using ALSA. Have you made the sound bar and/or HDMI work separately yet?

Comment: @XTL HDMI is ok, but Ive not got a USB bluetooth dongle yet for RPi to test with. I wondered if it might be possible in order to justify the purchase. I;ll check out ALSA

Comment: BT dongles are pretty affordable and a potentially useful thing to have. I've never tested audio over BT/HDMI.  Have a look at http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc for inspiration in configuring ALSA: